# Design Effect ZERO

Tags: sampling

Is Design Effect (DEFF) possible to be zero?

Note: Design Effect (DEFF) is defined as the ratio of the variance of an estimator
under a certain survey design (non SRS) to the variance of the estimator under
SRS (simple random sampling).

Comment: Consider an exhaustive sample of a finite population.